# Flask: On Button Click, Pass variable from Javascript to Flask

Tags: ajax, flask

I'm getting some data from the backend in Flask. What I want is on press of a button the backend query should change by increment the value of a variable which is embedded inside the query. I've gone through a couple of posts on stackoverflow which mentions to use AJAX to pass the data. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get it to work.

```
    home.html
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}

        {% for df in DF %}
                {{ df|safe }}
        {% endfor %}

        <div class=".col-lg-1" align="center">
          <form method="GET">
            <button type="submit" name="Previous_Btn" class="btn btn-dark" id="prev" value="1">Prev</button>
            <button type="submit" name="Next_Btn" class="btn btn-dark" id="next" value="1">Next</button> 
          </form>
        </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

```
    layouts.html
    <script type=text/javascript>

    var i=0;
    $('#next').click(function() {
      i=i+1;
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
              url: "/main",
              traditional: "true",
              data: JSON.stringify({i}),
              dataType: "json"
              });
        });
    </script>
```

So, on clicking the Next button in 'home.html', I'm incrementing that value in the javascript inside 'layouts.html' and passing it to the 'main.py' where the passed value will be used in constructing the backend query.

But I'm getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType in
`qry = "Select * from Table where Config='{}'".format(My_List[i])`

```
    main.py
    @app.route("/main", methods=["GET","POST"])
    def main():
        My_Data = pd.read_sql("select distinct Config from Table", conn).values.tolist()
        My_List = ['ABC','PQR','XYZ']
        i=0
        if request.method == 'GET':
            i = request.get_json()

        qry = "Select * from Table where Config='{}'".format(My_List[i])
        My_Data= pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
        return render_template('home.html', DF=[My_Data.to_html(classes='data', index=False)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You `POST` from Javascript but fetch JSON from request on Python side only if it's `GET`.